# How to add a comma in an array with functions?

Tags: php

I am trying to get the words "Space for Lease" and "New Development" to look like this:

Space for Lease, New Development

When "New Development" is not present, I would like the comma to be removed.

Space for Lease = 'property_status'

New Development = 'property_label'

You can currently call these two items by the following:

```
<p><?php echo houzez_taxonomy_simple('property_status'); ?>, 
   <?php echo houzez_taxonomy_simple('property_label'); ?>
</p>
```

I know that an array is needed with an if statement, but I am not too sure how to write it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Where is an array?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` statement to print the comma and the label.

```
<p><?php echo houzez_taxonomy_simple('property_status'); ?> 
   <?php $label = houzez_taxonomy_simple('property_label');
         if ($label) {
            echo ", $label";
         }
   ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Barmar, worked like a charm. Thank you for taking the time to respond to this...it really helped, PLUS, I learned a thing or two :)